# MySQL optimising geometry query

Tags: mysql, optimization, spatial

I have a query that correctly returns rows within X miles of a given `Point()` in order of closest distance first, but I am having problems optimizing the query which is currently taking 6-8 seconds to return 10 rows from a table containing about 250k rows.

The `geometry` `Location` column already has a spatial index.

My current query is:

```
SELECT *,  ROUND(ST_Distance_Sphere(Location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lng lat)', 4326)) / 1609.344, 2) as DistanceFromTargetInMiles   
       FROM Business
       -- within 5 miles
       WHERE  ST_Distance_Sphere(Location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lng lat)', 4326)) /1609.344 < 5
         -- show closest results first
         order by DistanceFromTargetInMiles 
         asc LIMIT 10
```

What can I do to improve the speed of this query? This is MySQL 8.0.1.3

Comment: It's not easy to speed it up.  [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) is my solution.

Comment: Limit your search by a bounding box first (in the where clause).  You'll need to do some calculations offline to find the size of the box which will give you at least 10 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add additional condition in where clause to check if the location withing envelope (posX - dist/2, posY - dist/2), (posX + dist/2, posY + dist/2). This is much easier calculation and if records NOT withing the envelope it will be excluded straight away and more resource expensive operation ST_Distance_Sphere would not be executed.

I tried to do this once and got improvements. However, I done this with quite old MySQL version so may be new version would not benefit from this approach.